# Laravel 5.1 Block users using Bican roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, roles, rbac

I was wondering, how I could ban people via [this](https://github.com/romanbican/roles) package...

So I'm currently using Laravel **5.1** and I'm trying to 'ban' users from my site.
I have a table called 'banned' wich has the following tructure:

```
    +---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+--+
    | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_DEFAULT | IS_NULLABLE | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | 
    +---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+--+
    | banned     | id          | NULL           | NO          | int       | NULL                     |
    | banned     | user_id     | NULL           | NO          | int       | NULL                     |
    | banned     | banned_by   | NULL           | NO          | int       | NULL                     |
    | banned     | reason      | NULL           | NO          | varchar   |                      255 |
    | banned     | expires     | NULL           | NO          | datetime  | NULL                     |
    | banned     | lifted      | NULL           | YES         | datetime  | NULL                     |
    | banned     | lifted_by   | NULL           | YES         | int       | NULL                     |
    +---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+--+
```

I also have the standard structure of the roles (bican roles).

Now, I want to be able to display a custom banned view to my banned users with the data from inside the 'banned' table.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a new middleware and call in in your controllers where users can acess the page it will check if they are banned

BannedMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BannedMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->is('banned')) {
            return view('BannedPageView');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and Edit your `kernal.php` under `protected $routeMiddleware` add this

```
'isBanned' => \App\Http\Middleware\BannedMiddleware::class,
```

Then in your controllers add this

```
public function __construct()
     {
         $this->middleware('isBanned');
     }
```

This will check if they are banned as they hit any Route in that controller.

**Edit**

---

To check everything globally for each and every request:

Make the same middleware and place this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CheckBanMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (User::CheckBan()) {
                $bandata = DB::table('banned')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->where('lifted', '=', Null)->where('expires', '>=', Carbon::now())->first();
                return response()->view('banned', ['bandata' => $bandata]);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your `User.php`, create a new function:

```
public static function CheckBan()
    {
        return DB::table('banned')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->where('lifted', '=', Null)->where('expires', '>=', Carbon::now())->exists();
    }
```

This function is made because I have another method to store bans etc...

Add the following line to `app/http/kernel.php` in the `protected $middleware` array.

```
\App\Http\Middleware\CheckBanMiddleware::class,
```

This provides to check the data BEFORE each and every request.

And you're done!

Comment: well I made new middleware today with a better method. Anyway thanks for the help :D

Comment: @RobinR IF its right could you please set it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: I've accepted your answer since that's a possible way to go too, BUT you can also add a function in your User model, call that function in your middleware and then register it in the kernel. I've provided my answer in your answer.

Comment: Oh yeah you can that would be the easier way